# Converting Cast V2 to CAF when it also uses DLNA + custom media path

Tags: google-cast, dlna

Looking to move an Android app from V2 to CAF but it also allows casting to both DLNA and custom devices. Those are currently handled via the MediaRouteSelector and MediaRouter callback which CAF apps are not supposed to touch. So how do you integrate these other media routes into a CAF app?